# IOS - using SCNLookAtConstraint does not seem to work the way I expected

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am learning SceneKit and trying to get the tip of a cone to point at the another node (a capsule) that is bouncing. Regardless of using the .orient on the cone, as soon as the SCNLookAtConstraint call gets made it re-orients the cone to the standard upright position so that the cone tip point straight up along the Y axis again and rock left and right as opposed to pointing its tip to the moving capsule which is to the rightof the cone. I tried changing the .pivot of the cone as well but that just seems to change the anchor point of the pivot but does not change the orientation of the cone.I need something like a SCNLookAtConstraint that indicates what point of the cone looks at the capsule?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the `pivot` property is the way to go. It allows you to change the anchor point, but also its orientation since its a transform.